# Qual a programação deve ser feita para usar o Spring Security com Jboss com anotações?

Tags: java, jboss, servlet, spring-security, jee

Conforme requisitos de um projeto que está em fase de pesquisa, preciso que um grande sistema distribuído funcione adequadamente com Spring, no exato momento estou com muitas dificuldades em integrar o Spring Security 3.2 com o JBoss EAP 6.3.

É um pouco difícil definir exatamente onde é a dificuldade, conforme vou fazendo novos testes novos obstáculos surgem, portanto preciso de uma referência concreta de código que funcione autenticação e autorização básica (Em Memória) para mapeamentos e chamadas de métodos.

Quais as configurações, parametrizações e programação deve ser feita para usar-los usando anotações (Servlet 3.1)?

Link para os códigos base que estão em constante evolução devido aos testes e estudos: http://bit.ly/EstudoSpringSecurityComJBoss

Comment: Há muitas formas de se configurar e usar o Spring Security, além de diferentes formas de integrá-lo com diferentes tecnologias, geralmente algum framework MVC como Spring MVC, mas efetivamente pode ser integrado com qualquer tecnologia baseada em Servlets. Sem definir exatamente as características do seu projeto e quais tecnologias ele vai adotar nas camadas de Visão e Controlador, é impossível falar sobre configurações e parâmetros sem reescrever ou simplesmente resumir a documentão já existente.

Comment: Para um projeto novo, sugiro fortemente ir de Sprint Boot, onde configurar e implementar um protótipo com Spring Security pode ser tão simples como um [tutorial de 15 minutos](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) (a depender, é claro, da experiência do desenvolvedor com Java). Além das facilidades do Spring Boot que é baseado em convenções (CoC), de quebra você ainda pode se livrar de vez dos containers e das dores de cabeça é que é manter e configurar esses monstrinhos, pois o Spring Boot funciona muito bom com um container *standalone*.

Comment: @utluiz, entendo, mas o projeto foi planejado com JBoss. Obrigado.

Comment: Inclusive já achei a resposta e estarei fazendo um pequeno tutorial quando tiver solucionado todos os problemas, parte da solução está nesta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73435/exemplo-do-spring-security-n%C3%A3o-funciona-no-jboss-o-que-deve-ser-feito-para-comp?lq=1#comment151084_73435

Comment: Delfino, pode explicar por que quer colocar a pergunta como Wiki? Talvez faça mais sentido colocar só a resposta (pra falar a verdade, não entendi bem seu objetivo com isso).

Comment: Se coloquei como wiki, foi um engano,não me lembro de ter marcado, porém acredito que a resposta se puder ser melhorada por todos seja muito valiosa para quem quer atuar com JBoss.

Comment: Você sinalizou pedindo pra transformar em wiki :) Então vou deixar como está, na hora de postar a resposta fica a seu critério colocá-la como wiki (me procure se precisar de ajuda).

Comment: Bem, poxa sinceramente não me lembro. Hehehe. Mas acho válido também como Wiki, muita gente deixa de usar o jboss porque acha complicado e a solução pode ser muito simples até onde cheguei nos estudos.

Comment: @bfavaretto, estou procurando replicar tal ação e não encontrei como foi feito, quando crio uma pergunta não tem para mim opção de marcar como sendo Wiki da Comunidade, e depois da pergunta enviada, não há para mim nem opção de sinalização, mesmo se eu edita-la há tal opção. Acho que deve realmente ter sido um engano. Obrigado.

Comment: @Delfino Acabei de configurar o Spring Security em um servidor WildFly(jBoss versão 8). Se tiver interesse posso compartilhar com você a configuração e o projeto no github.

Comment: Obrigado @adelmo00 quero sim, obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O projeto utiliza o Spring Security, JPA e JAX-RS. Não coloquei nenhum framework MVC ainda.
Testei a autenticação e está funcionando corretamente no WildFly 8.2.

Pom.xml foi gerado usando a ferramenta jBoss forge e fui incluindo outras dependências.

- [Pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/uC2wqSXZ)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/adelmo00/manager)

---

A classe SpringSecurityInitializer estende a classe abstrata AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer, que realiza internamente o registro do Servlet Filter criado para qualquer URL da aplicação

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

public SpringSecurityInitializer(){
    super(SecurityConfig.class);
}

@Override
protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
}}
```

Classe SecurityConfig que é responsável pela configuração:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "br.com.manager.config", " br.com.manager.service", "br.com.manager.dao" })
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Inject
private AuthenticateUser authenticateUser;

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticateUser);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl(UrlUtil.DASHBOARD_INDEX);

    http.formLogin().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");

    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl(UrlUtil.LOGIN_PAGE);
    http.logout().invalidateHttpSession(true);

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/dashboard/**").authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable();
}}
```

AuthenticateUser, usada para autenticar o usuário:

```
@Named
public class AuthenticateUser implements AuthenticationProvider   {

@Inject
private UsuarioService usuarioService;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

     Usuario usuario = usuarioService.loadUserByUsername(username);

     if (usuario == null || !password.equals(usuario.getPassword())) {
         throw new BadCredentialsException("Dados não encontrados.");
     }

     Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = usuario.getAuthorities();

     return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return true;
}}
```

Classe UsuarioService deve implementar a interface UserDetailsService :

```
@Named
public class UsuarioService implements UserDetailsService {

@Inject
private UsuarioDao usuarioDAO;

@Override
public Usuario loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return usuarioDAO.findByLogin(username);
}}
```

A classe Usuario deve implementar a interface UserDetails

```
@Entity(name = "Usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable, UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String login;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
private String senha;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Atribuicao> atribuicoes;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String cpf;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column(nullable = true)
private Boolean ativo;

@OneToOne
private Curriculo curriculo;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return atribuicoes;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return senha;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return login;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}}
```

A Classe Atribuicoes deve implementar a interface GrantedAuthority

```
@Entity
public class Atribuicao  implements Serializable,GrantedAuthority  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String nome;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return nome;
}}
```

Classe DatabaseConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "br.com.manager.model" });

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:jboss/datasources/ManagerDS");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}}
```

Classe UsuarioDAO

```
@Named
public class UsuarioDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public Usuario findByLogin(String login) {
    try{
        Query query = em.createQuery(" select u from Usuario u where u.login like :login").setParameter("login", login);
        return (Usuario) query.getSingleResult();
    }catch(NoResultException nre ){
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```