# Exemplo do Spring Security Não funciona no Jboss, o que deve ser feito para compatibilizar o exemplo?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, spring-security, spring-tools-suite

Continuando meus estudos no uso do **Spring Security** e **Servelet 3.0** estou tentando seguir os exemplos sugeridos no tutorial [Hello MVC - Running the insecure MVC Application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//hellomvc.html#running-the-insecuremvc-application), porém tais exemplos são para rodar no [TST](https://spring.io/tools/sts), mas estou precisando que os testes funcionem no **JBoss**, o que tem sido uma luta, então preparei meu ambiente com os plugins necessários obtidos conforme instruções do próprio site do Spring e JBoss.

No momento este teste, sem sequer adicionar a segurança, não funciona, apesar dos Logs do JBoss não apresentar nenhum erro, como listado abaixo:

```
11:34:19,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Iniciando a implantação do "spring-security-samples-insecuremvc.war" (runtime-name: "spring-security-samples-insecuremvc.war")
11:34:23,569 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011006: Nenhuma instalação do componente org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl opcional devido à uma exceção (habilite o nível do log DEPURAR para verificar a causa)
11:34:23,570 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011006: Nenhuma instalação do componente org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest opcional devido à uma exceção (habilite o nível do log DEPURAR para verificar a causa)
11:34:23,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Implantação do driver compatível-JDBC class org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver (versão 2.3)
11:34:23,641 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016012: A implantação deployment "spring-security-samples-insecuremvc.war" contém anotaçõs CDI mas o beans.xml não foi encontrado.
11:34:23,703 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JBAS018210: Registra o contexto da web: /sample
11:34:23,716 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sample]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.security.samples.config.MessageWebApplicationInitializer@7ee9271f]
11:34:23,852 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sample]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11:34:23,852 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
11:34:23,857 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jul 08 11:34:23 BRT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
11:34:23,918 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Registering annotated classes: [class org.springframework.security.samples.config.RootConfiguration]
11:34:24,517 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
11:34:24,697 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Creating embedded database 'testdb'
11:34:25,188 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
11:34:25,310 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
11:34:25,318 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
11:34:25,321 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) hibernate.properties not found
11:34:25,327 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:34:25,331 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
11:34:25,443 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.10.Final
11:34:25,456 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
11:34:25,514 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Binding entity from annotated class: org.springframework.security.samples.data.Message
11:34:25,559 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Bind entity org.springframework.security.samples.data.Message on table Message
11:34:25,624 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
11:34:25,646 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final-redhat-2
11:34:25,758 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
11:34:25,768 INFO  [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
11:34:25,771 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Using provided datasource
11:34:25,793 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
11:34:25,918 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Database ->
       name : HSQL Database Engine
    version : 2.3.2
      major : 2
      minor : 3
11:34:25,919 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Driver ->
       name : HSQL Database Engine Driver
    version : 2.3.2
      major : 2
      minor : 3
11:34:25,920 INFO  [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
11:34:25,921 INFO  [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
11:34:25,921 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
11:34:25,921 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
11:34:25,922 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JDBC batch size: 15
11:34:25,922 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
11:34:25,922 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Scrollable result sets: enabled
11:34:25,922 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
11:34:25,923 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Connection release mode: auto
11:34:25,923 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Default batch fetch size: 1
11:34:25,923 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Generate SQL with comments: disabled
11:34:25,924 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
11:34:25,924 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
11:34:25,924 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:34:25,925 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:34:25,926 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Query language substitutions: {}
11:34:25,926 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
11:34:25,926 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Second-level cache: enabled
11:34:25,926 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Query cache: disabled
11:34:25,926 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
11:34:25,927 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
11:34:25,927 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
11:34:25,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Statistics: disabled
11:34:25,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
11:34:25,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Default entity-mode: pojo
11:34:25,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Named query checking : enabled
11:34:25,932 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): disabled
11:34:25,945 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) building session factory
11:34:25,951 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@753d011
11:34:25,951 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveCharacterArrayClobType@f810fd9
11:34:25,951 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [wrapper_characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayClobType@62377782
11:34:25,951 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@27872a2e
11:34:25,951 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [java.sql.Blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@27872a2e
11:34:25,952 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [materialized_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@1ae24648
11:34:25,952 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@7d742ec1
11:34:25,952 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [java.sql.Clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@7d742ec1
11:34:25,952 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Type registration [wrapper_materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType@56a9c13f
11:34:26,138 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
11:34:26,142 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Running hbm2ddl schema update
11:34:26,143 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) fetching database metadata
11:34:26,147 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) updating schema
11:34:26,167 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) table not found: Message
11:34:26,170 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) table not found: Message
11:34:26,172 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) schema update complete
11:34:26,219 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Executing SQL script from class path resource [data.sql]
11:34:26,222 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Executed SQL script from class path resource [data.sql] in 3 ms.
11:34:26,594 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2741 ms
11:34:26,597 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sample]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
11:34:26,598 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
11:34:26,603 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 08 11:34:26 BRT 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
11:34:26,605 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Registering annotated classes: [class org.springframework.security.samples.mvc.config.WebMvcConfiguration]
11:34:26,737 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
11:34:27,188 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped "{[/**],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.security.samples.mvc.DefaultController.notFound()
11:34:27,193 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.samples.mvc.MessageController.list()
11:34:27,194 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped "{[//{id}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.security.samples.mvc.MessageController.delete(org.springframework.security.samples.data.Message,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:34:27,194 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped "{[/],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.samples.mvc.MessageController.create(org.springframework.security.samples.data.Message,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:34:27,195 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped "{[//{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.samples.mvc.MessageController.view(org.springframework.security.samples.data.Message)
11:34:27,195 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[form],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.security.samples.mvc.MessageController.createForm(org.springframework.security.samples.data.Message)
11:34:27,220 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
11:34:27,237 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
11:34:27,413 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 08 11:34:26 BRT 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
11:34:27,598 INFO  [org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
11:34:27,690 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1092 ms
11:34:27,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015865: A implantação substituída "spring-security-samples-insecuremvc.war" pela implantação "spring-security-samples-insecuremvc.war"
```

Como pode ser visto as `11:34:23,703` o contexto foi registrado corretamente, e as `11:34:26,598` o `Servlet Dispacher` foi registrado corretamente, e apartir dai todos os mapeamentos necessários para funcionamento da aplicação foram realizados com sucesso.

Veja na imagem abaixo a confirmação pela console de administração do Jboss:

[image: Console de Administração do JBoss]

Porém o JBoss não responde corretamente a URL: ** http://localhost:8080/sample** apresentando a mensagem de erro abaixo:

[image: Mensagem de Erro do JBoss]

Abaixo segue o meu arquivo POM.xml original com pequenos ajustes para o JBoss,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-samples-insecuremvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-security-samples-insecuremvc</name>
    <description>spring-security-samples-insecuremvc</description>

    <url>http://spring.io/spring-security</url>

    <organization>
        <name>spring.io</name>
        <url>http://spring.io/</url>
    </organization>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>rwinch</id>
            <name>Rob Winch</name>
            <email>rwinch@gopivotal.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</url>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-samples-messages-jc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.30</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <contextroot>/sample</contextroot>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>${contextroot}</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <jbossweb.contextroot>${contextroot}</jbossweb.contextroot>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/jboss-web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.7.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Estou usando o Eclipse Luna com os plugins para integração com Maven, Jboss e Spring IDE.

o que estou errando? o que falta?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68110/qual-a-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-deve-ser-feita-para-usar-o-spring-security-com-jboss-com-anot

Comment: `404` é por que não tem recurso sendo retornado nessa URL. Você está usando as mesmas configurações que citou na outra questão? Ou seja, retornando `home` na raiz? É isso?

Comment: @BrunoCésar a configuração é a padrão proposta pelo exemplo do Spring, pesquisando mais um pouco achei [esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25325159/2766598) que pode ser o caminho da solução, estou fazendo os ajustes, conforme consta é preciso usar "/*" no mapeamento raiz da aplicação web, e além disso tornar opcional a importação do Tomcat, (me esqueci disso)
Inclusive estarei disponibilizando no github os ajustes caso tenha sucesso: https://github.com/carlosdelfino/spring-security

Comment: Achei a solução do problema, tive que alterar o código no samples do spring-security, estarei jogando no github amanha, e posto aqui a solução, se alguém puder me ajudar testando em outro container, sem ser o jboss, seria bom assim podemos ver se as alterações impactam outros containers.