# É possível saber qual o Container JEE está sendo usado durante a inicialização do Dispatcher Servlet?

Tags: java-ee, spring, annotation, servlet-3

Depois de algumas dificuldades com o uso do `Spring Security` e `JBoss` usando anotações com base na `API Servlet 3` (Servlet 3.1 mais especificamente), descobri que ao usar o `Spring` com `JBoss`, em especial o JBoss EAP 6.1+, não se pode fazer o mapeamento do `Dispacher Servlet` para a URL "**/**" simplesmente, é preciso que tal mapeamento seja feito para a URL "**/***".

Para resolver tal problema cheguei a criar um fork para estudar tal problema, e este se encontra no link: https://github.com/carlosdelfino/spring-security/tree/rb4.0.1.RELEASE-JBoss-patch-1, onde já testei o exemplo "Insecure MVC" e tal correção resolve o problema.

Porém estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que será executada em diversos `containers`, e receio que possa a vir ter problemas com outros recursos, e assim eu precise parametrizar a inicialização do servlet.

Neste caso o `Spring` me oferece algum recurso para identificar em qual container está sendo executado?

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Este problema está relacionado com: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68110/qual-a-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-deve-ser-feita-para-usar-o-spring-security-com-jboss-com-anot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe para inicializar o WebApp que implemente a interface [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html).

Essa interface tem um único método que recebe um [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) e pelo [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) você pode pegar o nome do servidor.

```java
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println(context.getServerInfo());
    }

}
```

Saída no console:

[image: Tomcat]

[image: WildFly]

Comment: Adelmo, perfeito funcionou, como estou usando a classe `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, sobrepus o método e chamei o super, funcionou perfeitamente. https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8v49v91olo3of5/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-07-10%2015.04.58.png?dl=0